# How to print multiple values from session variable

Tags: php

multiple values from session variable example for session variable:-

```
I/P:- print_r($_SESSION['cart'][$id][$qty]);

O/P:- Array ( [0] => 2,3 [1] => 2,1 )
```

where

```
    [0] => 2,3 are id
```

and

```
     [1] => 2,1 are quantity
```

How to display the details of these ids and qty?

Comment: That's quite the unexpected output given those keys. Regardless, you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split up the data

Comment: How do you want them displayed

Answer (score 1):

That is not a very elegant way of storing this information so neither is the solution

```
$ids_a = explode(',', $_SESSION['cart'][$id][$qty][0]);
$qty_a = explode(',', $_SESSION['cart'][$id][$qty][1]);

foreach ( $ids_a as $idx => $the_id ) {
    echo 'id= ' . $the_id . ' Quantity = ' . $qty_a[$idx];
}
```

> Excuse the cumbersome variable names. I did not want to use something that might conflict with your existing variables.

Comment: Based on what OP gave, isn't `$_SESSION['cart'][$id][$qty][0]` a string?  "2,3"

Comment: @PatrickQ Ahh thanks completely missed that. Must be lunch time already :)

Comment: @PatrickQ Hopefully the sandwich I have been promised has re-linked my eyes to my brain :)

Comment: No worries.  It would have been more obvious from a `var_dump()` than a `print_r()`.  The construction of the session array also ins't logical to me.  Either that or the variable names that OP is using aren't appropriate for what's being done.

Comment: @PatrickQ A complete mess, but ours is just to answer and die :)